# $\Bbb Z_n $ is an injective $\Bbb Z_n$-module

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, injective-module

I am trying to prove or disprove that $\Bbb Z_n $ is an injective $\Bbb Z_n$-module, where $n$ is an integer $>1$.

If $n$ is a prime, then $\Bbb Z_n$ is a field, so every $\Bbb Z_n$-module is free, and hence projective.  I know that for a ring $R$, every $R$-module is projective iff every $R$-module is injective, so in this case $\Bbb Z_n$ is an injective $\Bbb Z_n$-module.

But I have no idea to handle the case where $n$ is not a prime. Any hints?

Comment: The proposition is true... did you look at it with the Baer criterion?

Comment: @rschwieb I know what it is, but how does it imply the result? Every ideal of $\Bbb Z_n$ is $(d+n\Bbb Z)\simeq \Bbb Z_{n/d}$ for some divisor  $d$ of $n$, and I have to show that every $\Bbb Z_n$-module homomorphism $(d+n\Bbb Z)\to R$ can be extended to a homomorphism $\Bbb Z_n\to R$, but I can't see this.

Comment: What do you mean “how does it imply the result?”  You just check that this ring and this module satisfy the criterion, and it asserts the module is injective. It looks like someone has written a solution to that effect now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand\ideal{\mathfrak}$This holds, in general, on every PID $A$.

Let $\ideal a$ be an ideal of $A/Aa$ and $\varepsilon:\ideal a\to A/Aa$ be an $A/Aa$-module homomorphism.
Then $\ideal a=Ab/Aa$ for some $b\in A$ and $a\in Ab$, so that $a=bc$ for some $c\in A$.
Let $y\in A$ such that $\varepsilon(b+Aa)=y+Aa$.
Then there exists $d\in A$ such that $cy=da=dbc$ that's $y=bd$.
Thus the $A$-module homomorphism
\begin{align}
&A\to A/Aa&&x\in A\mapsto dx+Aa
\end{align}
factors through a projection $A\to A/Aa$ modulo $Aa$ giving rise to an $A$-module homomorphism $A/Aa\to A/Aa$ extending $\varepsilon$.